# How do I make placements within my resume?

Tags: indentation, cv

I'm currently writing a resume.

Consider the below LaTeX bit of code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\title{\bfseries\Huge Jo Bloggs}
\author{1 Blogg Road, London, London, WC1 1AA \\ bloggs@bloggs.com}
\date{}

\usepackage{array, xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{gobble}
section*{Experience}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
July '13--Present&{\bf Intern and Intern UK, United Kingdom}\\
&Doing interny stuff on two different placements\\[2.5pt]\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

It's great and what I require for my needs bar one crucial element. However, I want to be able to create a sub-section within this experience for me two write separately about two different placements.

So I want it to read:

```
July '13 - Present Intern at Intern UK, United Kindom Doing interny stuff on three different placements
      Placement 1: Coffee holder and maker
                   I made the coffee whilst pretending to like my colleagues.

      Placement 2: Photocopier master
                   Can do single/double-sided photocopying at graduate level.
```

Any advice?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your complete with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `\usepackage{enumitem}` to your preamble (before `\begin{document}`) then you can use the `description` environment with some tweaks:

[Edit: moved the `description` environment inside `tabular]

```
\section*{Experience}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
July '13--Present&{\bf Intern and Intern UK, United Kingdom}\\
&Doing interny stuff on two different placements\\
July '13--Present&{\bf Intern at Intern UK, United Kindom}\\
&Doing interny stuff on three different placements
\\
&\parbox{0.8\textwidth}{
\begin{description}[leftmargin=7em,style=multiline]
  \item[Placement 1:] Coffee holder and maker\\
                   I made the coffee whilst pretending to like my colleagues.
  \item[Placement 2:] Photocopier master\\
                   Can do single/double-sided photocopying at graduate level.
\end{description}
}
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

(Btw your `\section*` command is missing its `\`.)

Comment: Hi, I've just done that but the text is on the margins where the dates are rather where the text is. Can you offer some advice?

Comment: I think the tabular function is forcing the text to go in the first column.

Comment: @H.A. No, I think that there were a few typos with the tabular. I have just added an edit of the tabular environment that I think is what you were aiming for.

Comment: Ahh, what if I wanted to put the description list into the tabular bit. That's what I require.

Comment: @H.A. If you want this then to move  `description` environment inside the tabular you to be in "paragraph" mode, so use `\parbox`. I have edited my solution making the `\parbox` 80% of the width of the page. Adjust as needed.